# Does JavaScript ignore the remaining lines of code in a function after it makes a recursive call?

Tags: javascript

I am building a minesweeper game in JavaScript and I am running into a problem while trying to clear the adjacent empty cells when a cell without a mine is clicked.

I am using a function called clearEmptySpace() to check if the variable adjacentMines is greater than 0 on all cells adjacent to the one clicked. 
If the adjacentMines variable is 0 on any of the checked cells I call the checkCell() function which uncovers the cell and then calls clearEmptySpace(), with the new cell location.

If clearEmptySpace() finds a cell with 1 or more adjacent mines it calls checkCell() with a flag to ensure clearEmptySpace() is not called again with that cell location.

The issue is clearEmptySpace() checks the cell directly above itself and when it finds the cell above it has an adjacentMines value of 0 it calls checkCell() with the cell position above itself as intended but does not continue checking the other directions after the function call is made.

The only time the next check (Upper left cell) is made is when the cell above has 1 or more adjacent mine and the following checkCell() does not re-call clearEmptySpace().

Is the second clearEmptySpace() call stopping the current clearEmptySpace() from further execution? if so how do I go about fixing this issue?

For simplicity's sake the clearEmptySpace() code provided only checks the cell directly above and the upper left cell.

```
function checkCell(cell,onlyOnce = false){
    var cellLocation = cell.id.toString();
    var clickedCell = cellLocation.split(',');
    if(cellArray[clickedCell[0]][clickedCell[1]].hasMine){
        cell.innerHTML = "M"
        gameOver();
    }else{
        cellArray[clickedCell[0]][clickedCell[1]].flagged = false;
        if(cellArray[clickedCell[0]][clickedCell[1]].adjacentMines > 0){
            getFontColor(cell);
            cell.innerHTML = cellArray[clickedCell[0]][clickedCell[1]].adjacentMines.toString();
        }else{
            cell.innerHTML = "0";
        }
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "#EBEBEB";
        if(!onlyOnce && !cellArray[clickedCell[0]][clickedCell[1]].adjacentMines){
            clearEmptySpace(cell);
        }
    }
    cellArray[clickedCell[0]][clickedCell[1]].hidden = false;
}

_____________________________________________________________________________

function clearEmptySpace(inputCell){
    var cellLocation = inputCell.id.toString();
    var currentCell = cellLocation.split(',');

    var targetCellLocation = new Array();
    targetCellLocation = [currentCell[0]-1,currentCell[1]+1];
    var targetCell = document.getElementById(targetCellLocation[0].toString()+","+targetCellLocation[1].toString());

    if(currentCell[0] > 0){
        if(!cellArray[currentCell[0]-1][currentCell[1]].adjacentMines){
            alert("The cell directly above has no adjacent mines");
            targetCellLocation = [currentCell[0]-1,currentCell[1]];
            checkCell(document.getElementById(targetCellLocation[0].toString()+","+targetCellLocation[1].toString()));
        }else{
            alert("The cell directly above has at least one adjacent mine");
            targetCellLocation = [currentCell[0]-1,currentCell[1]];
            checkCell(document.getElementById(targetCellLocation[0].toString()+","+targetCellLocation[1].toString()),true);
        }
        if(currentCell[1] > 0 ){
            if(!cellArray[currentCell[0]-1][currentCell[1]-1].adjacentMines){
                alert("The cell on the upper left has no adjacent mines");
                targetCellLocation = [currentCell[0]-1,currentCell[1]-1];
                checkCell(document.getElementById(targetCellLocation[0].toString()+","+targetCellLocation[1].toString()));
            }else{
                alert("The cell on the upper left has at least one adjacent mine");
                targetCellLocation = [currentCell[0]-1,currentCell[1]-1];
                checkCell(document.getElementById(targetCellLocation[0].toString()+","+targetCellLocation[1].toString()),true);
            }
        }
       }
}
```

Comment: no, it does not. calling a function does not imply a return from the current function (recursion make no difference to this)

Comment: When it encounters a recursive call, it will resolve it like any other function call - execute the function and when complete, continue with the next line. Whether the function call is to the same function or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Did you check your browser's console? Your description points quite naturally to an Error thrown somewhere, or an infinite loop, in which case, yes, the remaining of the function would never happen. For us here, it's quite hard to get our heads over your code, recursion is often hard to follow just by reading, but here we are not even sure how your data is formatted. Can you please try to generate an [MCVE] (all the DOM references are probably not needed, your grid doesn't need to be quite big).

Comment: when I add an alert that displays the cellLocation variable after the first check I never get the alert for any of the function calls except the last one where it cannot check the above tile because the y position is 0 and the check is ignored. so the rest of the checks are not being done by the initial function

Comment: wow "alert" as in `alert()`? I missed that in your code... Yes, this does block js execution but it should restart after you close it. Now, please use the [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) to debug. And use it to log the values you are getting like `console.log(targetCellLocation, targetCell)`

Comment: I didn't include the alert call in the example code. I used the console to debug like you suggested by putting console.log(cellLocation); after the initial check. if I click the cell at x:0 y:5 it does not print 0,5 to the console and instead prints 0,0 which is the last instance of the function call (checking the above tile until it can no longer because the top of the board has been reached)

Comment: Great so you know that it's broken there already. It has nothing to do with what comes after. Find why you have `0,0` instead of your expected `0,5`. Once again, we miss an [MCVE] to help you more. You'll have to dig in there yourself ;-)